# 4 colour deck in hand history questions

Tags: feature-request

What do people think about making all the suits in the hand posts be 4 color decks?

Personally I think this greatly improves the readability of the hand histories when they are in text format. It seems as though the standard format in many online poker sites has a more highly readable format that often incorporates the 4 color deck.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to format hands, and yes, 4 colour decks are a great improvement.

I've always used the 2+2 format for hands as I feel it's the easiest to read and modify. Here's a good converter that can be used.

[FlopTurnRiver Hand Converter](http://poker-tools.flopturnriver.com/Hand-Converter.php)