# Do we need a hand history converter?

Tags: feature-request, formatting, hand-history-questions, card-renderer

Like [Deuces Cracked](http://www.deucescracked.com/forums) and and [Two plus Two](http://forumserver.twoplustwo.com/1/two-plus-two/) forums, I think if we had a hand history converter, that would be nice.

Comment: Related (implemented) request: [Can we get markup to help with hand histories?](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/10346)

Answer (score 4):

Having **hands history converter is a must** for Poker.SE. As the user's level raise from novice (as it is now) to strong amateurs / professionals most of questions will concern the analysis of specific hands.

Answer (score 3):

Hand history convertors are quite useful in my opinion.

I would definately say its worth having one, if its an option.